# Centering a div, WITHIN a div inside a div - Any advice?

Tags: css, html, center, margin

I know it's not that much of programming, more of a coding. I'm facing a theoretically simple to solve problem :

Project: A multi-purpose nice looking set of pricing tables

Problem: How to center a group of 3 pricing tables inside the browser's window.

Solutions that I've tried: "margin: 0 auto" on .main class and .container class

Below is the link to download a piece of code and a graphical explanation of the goal that I want to achieve. I would be extremely thanful for any help in resolving this issue. Cheers !

Link to the index.html and css folder + Graphical explanation of the problem : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/tlcld7k6lfhmb3w/YMJ3_5MR6I

Comment: I need the css-files too. Could you upload them to something like http://jsfiddle.net/ that would be easier to debug.

Comment: Set correct `width` and `margin: 0 auto;`to container div.

Comment: Jere ! Thanks for reminding me about jsfiddle.net, I was thinking long 'what was that online code pasting platform' and couldn't remind myself. Here is the code on jsfiddle.net :

http://jsfiddle.net/b2c8q/ (You'll have to separate two css parts somehow as for some reason inline css doesn't work well here. Or maybe it's me doing something wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is pretty easy:
Your .center class IS centred. But your price-tables have a width of 25% - that means as long as you have only three container with that class there will be a space with the width of 25% on the right hand side.

Solution:
Eather add a fourth price-option or set the width of .cp-column to 33% ;)

Now it looks like:

```
.center {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
.cp-column {
 width: 25%;
 float: left;
}
```

Change that to

```
.center {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
.cp-column {
 width: 33%;
 float: left;
}
```

Comment: Jere, one more question to you. I have changed it correctly to 33% in cp-column but for some reason all the css3 animation effects are not working. What ws supposed to be going on is a flipside 3d effect upon hovering on the pricing table. It was revealing a hidden text but right now nothing is going on after hovering your mouse cursor on it. Any ideas why it can not work ? 

P.s. I've checked it under few browsers and still without a luck.

Comment: can you upload a jsfiddle again?

Answer (score 2):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/V6Jxj/)**

`margin: 0 auto;` should work fine check the demo. You might have forgot to restrict the width of div.

It doesn't matter if you are using margin auto technique in a div within a div as long as parent div's covers the entire width.

Comment: Thank you as well for your answer. However, I've picked up Jere's as the one resolving my initial problem.

Comment: No problem :), there wasn't any fiddle from your side when i posted my answer, I am glade your problem was resolved.